# Unwanted white space when I go into mobile view

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

Does someone know how to remove this white space?
This only occurs when I'm in mobile view.
Image of the problem. Untitled:
[image: Untitled]

I tried using responsive instead of fluid but that doesn't solve the problem completely, the image is just scaled up.

HTML code of these boxes

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center bg-dark">
    <h2 class="mb-0 text-white">Za miran život bez stresa!</h2>
    <br>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">321 GARAŽNO MESTO</p>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">+ priključci za električni automobil, auto-perionica u garaži.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="assets/img/slikablok2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="assets/img/slikablok3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center bg-dark">
    <h2 class="text-white"> SPOJITE SE SA PRIRODOM! </h2>
    <br>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white">Naša inspiracija – Gorica, simbol je magičnog lijepog parka koji se prostire 
    parkom površine od čak 1,4 hektara.</p>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white">Njime poručujemo da se spojite sa prirodom, procvetate i napredujete.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center bg-dark">
    <h2 class="mb-0 text-white">Za sve vremenske prilike i potpuno uživanje.</h2>
    <br>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">GRIJANJE I HLAĐENJE</p>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">U stambenom dijlu objekta primenjen je sistem grijanja i hlađenja svih prostorija, najsavremenijom tehnologijom.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="assets/img/slikablok4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your class `img-fluid` for `w-100 h-100` and `object-fit: cover` in css

```css
img {
  object-fit: cover
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center bg-dark">
    <h2 class="mb-0 text-white">Za miran život bez stresa!</h2>
    <br>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">321 GARAŽNO MESTO</p>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">+ priključci za električni automobil, auto-perionica u garaži.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" class="w-100 h-100">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2"  class="w-100 h-100">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center bg-dark">
    <h2 class="text-white"> SPOJITE SE SA PRIRODOM! </h2>
    <br>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white">Naša inspiracija – Gorica, simbol je magičnog lijepog parka koji se prostire parkom površine od čak 1,4 hektara.</p>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white">Njime poručujemo da se spojite sa prirodom, procvetate i napredujete.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center bg-dark">
    <h2 class="mb-0 text-white">Za sve vremenske prilike i potpuno uživanje.</h2>
    <br>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">GRIJANJE I HLAĐENJE</p>
    <p class="mb-0 text-white-50">U stambenom dijlu objekta primenjen je sistem grijanja i hlađenja svih prostorija, najsavremenijom tehnologijom.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3"  class="w-100 h-100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Much better, thank you so much, 1 more question if I may.

Comment: yes of course, say it

Comment: Is there a way to rotate these pictures (boxes, with text) to be more horizontally not vertically? But only when I go into mobile view

Comment: can you give an example of what you want ?

Comment: https://startbootstrap.com/previews/grayscale On this website you will see a similar page like mine but in this case, when you resize the browser into mobile view (if I can say like that), those images, and boxes are changed horizontally

Comment: gotcha,  so where you have `<div class="col-6"` change to  `<div class="col-md-6">`

Comment: That's it, from the bottom of my heart thank you again